# Нумерованный список для рейтинга Python

Tags: python, список

Есть список кортежей:

```
[('Строка', 'Строка', 9962), ('Строка', 'Строка', 1150), ('Строка', 'Строка', 9001)]
```

Нужно привести его к следующему виду:

```
1. Строка Строка 99632
2. Строка Строка 1150
3. Строка Строка 9001
```

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону функции enumerate

Comment: Где получить? Как получить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lst = [('Строка', 'Строка', 9962), ('Строка', 'Строка', 1150), ('Строка', 'Строка', 9001)]

for number, info in enumerate(lst):
    print ("%i. %s %s %s" % (number, *info))
```

`enumerate(list)` отдаёт список пар (индекс, значение). Пробежавшись по нему и грамотно подставив в вывод нужные значения мы и получим желаемый результат в stdout.

Answer (score 1):

В виде списка:

```
res = ['{}. {}'.format(i,' '.join(map(str, t))) for i,t in enumerate(data, 1)]
print(res)
#['1. Строка Строка 9962', '2. Строка Строка 1150', '3. Строка Строка 9001']
```

в виде строки:

```
res = '\n'.join('{}. {}'.format(i,' '.join(map(str, t))) for i,t in enumerate(data, 1))
print(res)
#1. Строка Строка 9962
#2. Строка Строка 1150
#3. Строка Строка 9001
```

Comment: или так `print(*res, sep='\n')`

Comment: @Andrey, можно и так. Это будет зависить от того что нужно автору вопроса - просто вывести все на печать, записать в файл или что-то другое...